# How to setup odoo 10 for development in macOS

Tags: odoo

I have installed all the pre-requests as in the tutorials.

When I tried to run odoo by using the following command,

```
./odoo.py --addons-path=addons,../mymodules --db-filter=mydb$
```

I am getting the following error message.

```
-bash: ./odoo.py: No such file or directory
```

[image]

```
Jinn-MacBook-Air:odoo juasoft$ ./odoo-bin 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./odoo-bin", line 9, in <module>
    odoo.cli.main()
  File "/Users/juasoft/git/odoo/odoo/cli/command.py", line 64, in main
    o.run(args)
  File "/Users/juasoft/git/odoo/odoo/cli/server.py", line 164, in run
    main(args)
  File "/Users/juasoft/git/odoo/odoo/cli/server.py", line 122, in main
    odoo.tools.config.parse_config(args)
  File "/Users/juasoft/git/odoo/odoo/tools/config.py", line 315, in parse_config
    odoo.netsvc.init_logger()
  File "/Users/juasoft/git/odoo/odoo/netsvc.py", line 120, in init_logger
    resetlocale()
  File "/Users/juasoft/git/odoo/odoo/tools/translate.py", line 1185, in resetlocale
    for ln in get_locales():
  File "/Users/juasoft/git/odoo/odoo/tools/translate.py", line 1154, in get_locales
    lang = locale.getdefaultlocale()[0]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 545, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 477, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
Jinn-MacBook-Air:odoo juasoft$
```

Comment: Try exporting this variables in the current window `export LC_ALL=es_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and try again, If it works add it to your bash profile to make it permanent (Note that It must not necessarily be en_US)

Comment: @danidee : Thank You !!! It worked ...

Comment: @danidee : And how to add this to bash profile ?

Comment: I've added an answer below

Comment: Thanks a lot for the question and as well as for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to your home directory

```
cd ~
```

Edit .bash_profile (with vim or any text editor)

```
vim .bash_profile
```

Add the following lines to it

```
export LC_ALL=es_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

And then finally `source` the file to make the changes take effect immediately (without this you'll have to logout and login again as `.bash_profile` is executed only on login)

```
source .bash_profile
```